# How to set collectionView sizeForItemAt from Observable RxSwift

Tags: swift, uikit, rx-swift, collectionview

I have some issues when trying to make the height of my collection view cells dynamic. The height data is inside my enum `Observable<[MovieSection]>` array. As far as I know, RxSwift doesn't provide a `sizeForItemAt` delegate function.

So, how can I pass my `Observable<[MovieSection]>` array to the 'sizeForItemAt' delegate so that I can switch my enum based on its case and retrieve the height?

```
enum MovieSection {
    case header(height: Double, movie: Movie)
    case horizontal(title: String, height: Double, items: [Movie])
}

class ViewModel {
   private var _sections = BehaviorRelay<[MovieSection]>(value: [])
   
   var sections: Observable<[MovieSection]>? {
       return _sections.asObservable()
   }


   func getData() {
     //items and movie from somewhere i get from network/mock

     let sectionsData: [MovieSection] = [
           .header(height: 270, movie: popular[1]),
           .horizontal(title: "Popular", height: 230, items: popular),
           .horizontal(title: "Top Rated", height: 230, items: topRated)
      ]
      _sections.accept(sectionsData)
   }
}


class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
   var viewModel = ViewModel()
   @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupBindings()
        viewModel.getData()
    }

   private func setupBindings() {
        viewModel.sections
            .bind(to: collectionView.rx.items) { collectionView, row, item in
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
                
                switch item {
                case .header(_, let movie):
                    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HeaderSectionCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! HeaderSectionCell
                    cell.configure(with: movie.backdropPath)
                    return cell
                case .horizontal(let title, _, let movies):
                    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HorizontalMoviesCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! HorizontalMoviesCell
                    cell.configure(with: title, items: movies)
                    return cell
                }
            }
            .disposed(by: bag)
        
        collectionView.rx.setDelegate(self)
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }

}

//MARK: UICollectionView Delegate
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        //Here i want pass my height from my [MovieSection] array of enum so i can access my height

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 230)
    }
}
```

What I've done before is directly accessing the value from the BehaviorRelay, so I can directly access the array without returning new Observable variable

like this:

```
func getSectionsValue() -> [MovieSection] {
    return _sections.value
}
```

My expecting to get access from my `Observable<[MovieSection]>` in `sizeForItemAt` CollectionView so i can access my height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always used constraints to set the height of cells. I suggest you add a height constraint on the cells' content views and pass the height into the cell just like you do the other configuration data.

However, if you want to continue with using `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` then a BehaviorRelay is required.

The simplest method is to add one to the view controller and bind it to the `sections` observable...

```
let heightForItemAt = BehaviorRelay<[CGFloat]>(value: [])

func setupBindings() { 
    viewModel.sections
        .map { $0.map { $0.height } }
        .bind(to: heightForItemAt)
        .disposed(by: bag)
    // the rest of the method as you have it...
}
```

The above assumes you have this:

```
extension MovieSection {
    var height: Double {
        switch self {
        case .header(let height, _), .horizontal(_, let height, _):
            return height
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your delegate method, you can access the `heightForItemAt` relay's value to get the height.

---

If you want you could follow my article [Convert a Swift Delegate to RxSwift Observables](https://danielt1263.medium.com/convert-a-swift-delegate-to-rxswift-observables-f52afe77f8d6). Then you could do it like this:

```
viewModel.sections
    .map { [collectionView] sections in
        sections.map { CGSize(width: collectionView!.frame.width, height: $0.height) }
    }
    .bind(to: collectionView.rx.sizeForItemAt)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

But it still requires a BehaviorSubject (inside the delegate proxy.)

Comment: so if i using your suggest to pass height into the cell, then we need to set collectionview layout estimateItemSize to automatic ? @Daniel T.

Comment: Yes. You might also want to pass in the cell width. If you want the cells to get wider when the device rotates, you will have to adjust as well.

Comment: thanks for your suggest btw, you'r really good on reactive programming,
another question Daniel, idk if i can ask here or need to create another question thread. Just to ask about viper + rxswift, can i put observable in presenter than i subscribe directly from viewController, or still use delegate to pass data from presenter to view/viewController ? @Daniel T.

Comment: I wouldn't use a delegate. I try to make sure all data gets pushed around via Observables instead of mixing and matching closures, delegates, inheritance, UIControls and so on... Have you seen my [VIPER, RxSwift-ified](https://danielt1263.medium.com/viper-rxswift-ified-1ec3ae8ab9a6) blog post?